# Club the two commands i.e output of first as input to the second command

Tags: shell, pipe, aix

I wish to club the below two Steps whereby the output of Step 1 i.e the PORTS should go as input to Step 2.

Step 1:

The below command gets me the port numbers from a file.

```
genpwdfile dec -in test/test.cfg -out /tmp/dec.out |grep PORT_NUM /tmp/dec.out | cut -d '=' -f2 ; grep MONITOR_PORT /tmp/dec.out  | cut -d '=' -f2
```

Output:

```
33027
13041
```

Step 2:

The below command kills the PID [which comes as output of Step 1] occupying the ports.

```
lsof -i:33027 2>/dev/null | grep -v PID | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 

lsof -i:13041 2>/dev/null | grep -v PID | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Sample /tmp/dec.out

```
Test_DIR=/tmp
PORT_NUM=33027
TEST_PORT_WORK=7777
MONITOR_PORT=13041
```

I'm dealing with AiX 6.1 System

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: What is the point of the `genpwdfile` command if you then just `grep PORT_NUM /tmp/dec.out`? You aren't connecting these in any way.

Comment: The `genpwdfile` creates `dec.out` file

Comment: Then why are you piping to `grep PORT_NUM /tmp/dec.out`? And what does the second `grep` do? The one in `grep MONITOR_PORT /tmp/dec.out`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a shell loop. You can join your two `grep` commands into a single one, and there's no point in piping the `genpwdfile` if it creates a file. Try this:

```
genpwdfile dec -in test/test.cfg -out /tmp/dec.out &&
    grep -E 'PORT_NUM|MONITOR_PORT' /tmp/dec.out | cut -d '=' -f2 |
        while read -r port; do
            lsof -i:"$port" 2>/dev/null | 
                awk 'NR>1{print $2}' 
        done | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: The answer did not help! the two `grep` in Step1 gets me two ports. The answer ` | while read -r port; do` only reads one port and does not loop twice for each port. Also, `... | cut -d '=' -f2 ; grep MONITOR_PORT /tmp/dec.out  |  ...` gets me the second port number. two greps returns two port numbers.

Comment: @Ashar thanks for the edit, that made things clearer. Try the updated answer.

Comment: `grep 'PORT_NUM\|MONITOR_PORT' /tmp/dec.out` doesn't grep for both entries in the file for the AiX I have.

Comment: @Ashar really? I could have sworn the `\|` was completely portable. Does it work if you change that to `grep -E 'PORT_NUM|MONITOR_PORT' /tmp/dec.out`?

Comment: `grep -E 'PORT_NUM|MONITOR_PORT' /tmp/dec.out` Works !! but `grep 'PORT_NUM\|MONITOR_PORT' /tmp/dec.out` does not.

Comment: @Ashar OK. I have no idea why, but maybe the `\|` is a GNU extension. So, does the updated answer work?